# useState does not set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, rendering

First of all, yes, I talked with ChatGPT, it does not give a working answer.
The main is that I want an image to be rendered.
Why in my case the setter does not work?

Probably the error lies on the surface, I am a newbie so please do not be strict.

I am trying to set setMeme in two places, but it does not work.
What's horroring for me is that I do not receive any error.

I screened a few sites, but solutions mostly rely on "useEffect", and did not help

this did not help:

[The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

```
import React from "react"; import memesData from "../memesData.js"; import { useState, useEffect } from "react"; import front_img from "../../public/images/front_meme.png";

function importAll(r) {
    return r.keys().map(r);   }
     const images = importAll(require.context('./', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/)); //alert(images); // Create a require.context for the images folder //const imagesContext = require.context("../images", true);

export default function Meme() {
    const [memeImg, setMeme] = useState("");
    const [word , setWord] = useState("");
    //setWord("dfb")
    //alert(word);

    const getMemeImage = async () => {
      const memesArray = memesData.data.memes;
      const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * memesArray.length);
      const selectedMeme = memesArray[randomNumber];
    
      setMeme("svsdsd");
      // No console.log here
      if (selectedMeme && selectedMeme.url) {
        setMeme(selectedMeme.url);
      }
      
    };

useEffect(() => {
            console.log("Meme Image:", memeImg);
          }, [memeImg]);
    
     // Add memeImg as a dependency for 

     return (
    <div>
      <form className="form">
        <input type="text" className="form--input" />
        <input type="text" className="form--input" />
        <button onClick={getMemeImage} className="form-button">
          Get a new meme image
        </button>
      </form>
      <img className="meme--image" src={front_img} alt="" />
      
        <img
          className="meme--image"
          src={memeImg}
          // imagesContext(`./${memeImage}`).default 
          alt=""
        />
      
    </div>   ); }
```

memesData.js

```
const memesData = {
success: true,
data: {
    memes: [
        {
            id: "3242213",
            name: "Good Meme 1",
            url: "./Portfolio/meme_generator/public/images/good_meme_1.png",
            width: 350,
            height: 400,
            box_count: 3,
        },
        {
            id: "3224",
            name: "Good Meme 2",
            url: "./Portfolio/meme_generator/public/images/good_meme_2.png",
            width: 400,
            height: 300,
            box_count: 2,
        },
        {
            id: "234213",
            name: "Good meme 3",
            url: "./Portfolio/meme_generator/public/images/good_meme_3.png",
            width: 300,
            height: 400,
            box_count: 3,
        },
        { 
            id: "5672213",
            name: "Good meme 4",
            url: "./Portfolio/meme_generator/public/images/good_meme_4.png",
            width: 500,
            height: 400,
            box_count: 3,
        },
        {
            id: "456415",
            name: "Good meme 5",
            url: "./Portfolio/meme_generator/public/images/good_meme_5.png",
            width: 200,
            height: 500,
            box_count: 5,
        },
        {
            id: "38654673",
            name: "Good meme 6",
            url: "./Portfolio/meme_generator/public/images/good_meme_6.png",
            width: 400,
            height: 350,
            box_count: 7,
        },
        {},
    ]
}
```

}
export default memesData;

samran feli's answer helped, so the image starts to load. So I at least started getting an error in the console when I click,

The error is:

```
good_meme_2.png:1     GET http://localhost:3000//public/images/good_meme_2.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: console.log runs before setting the state

Answer (score 1):

Hooks need to be at the top level of a component, or within another hook. You've Put yours within a callback.

Comment: took your note, 

accoriding to samran felis answer nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

you used useeffect hook inside a callback function which is getMemeImage it will not work properly. move useeffect outside getMemeImage function.

if you see the console log in useeffect is showing the updated data and image is still not showing the try to give some static width and height to the image

Answer (score 0):

```
setMeme("svsdsd");
// No console.log here
if (selectedMeme && selectedMeme.url) {
setMeme(selectedMeme.url)};
  }
```

You are setting the `meme` outside the `hook`, which will run only once, what you can is add this logic inside the `useEffect` with `selectedMeme` as dependency array, so whenever the selectedMeme changes the setMeme will be setted.

```
 useEffect(() => {
   if (selectedMeme && selectedMeme.url) {
      setMeme(selectedMeme.url);
   }
  }, [selectedMeme]);
 };
```

Comment: Tried you approach, the "memeImg" variable still does not set

Answer (score 0):

1. you should export your data in memesData.js (and closing "{" is missed):

```js
export const memesData = {
    // ...
};
```

and import it so:

```js
import {memesData} from "../memesData.js";
```

2. getMemeImage:

```js
const memesArray = memesData?.data.memes;
const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * memesArray.length);
const selectedMeme = memesArray[randomNumber];
if (selectedMeme && selectedMeme.url) {
    setMeme(selectedMeme.url);
}
```

3. your button should have `type="button"` to prevent form submits and page reloads:

```html
<button type="button" onClick={getMemeImage} className="form-button">
    Get a new meme image
</button>
```

Comment: I just copy pasted, no changes, the src attribute do not set

Comment: can I have a look at memesData.js?

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope it would help you.

Comment: The first point is not necessary, but I checked to be safe,
Nobody still gave me the answer, 
the 3rd point changed the situation, so now I am getting another error, the image started to load, but

////////
GET http://localhost:3000//public/images/good_meme_2.png 404 (Not Found)
//////

the request breaks

Answer (score 0):

Hooks shouldn't be used in nested scope !!!